# CGI and Apache Struts

Tags: java, struts, cgi

I am reading [struts in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1930110502) ,and it says CGI is one of the enabling technologies of struts, Could someone help me to understand what is the relationship between CGI and struts?

Comment: _CGI is one of the enabling technologies_ i don't think so because it's already outdated.

Comment: And Struts is almost as outdated as CGI. Add more context to your quote. CGI is one of the enabling technologies of what?

Comment: @JBNizet updated , what is the popular framework like struts everybody used?

Comment: There are many of them: Spring MVC, Grails, Play, Stripes, Struts2, JSF...

Comment: Some of them I have heard about it like Spring MVC and Struts 2.thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been down voted . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGI and Struts are two "web application frameworks".  I'm sure a lot of people might disagree with the categorization of CGI as a web application framework, and I suspect the term didn't exist back when CGI was the main framework for processing requests for dynamic web resources, but it's essentially the same thing.

A web applicaiton framework simply provides out of the box infrastructure to handle the chores that must be done for the processing of every web request.  These include unmarshaling of incoming request parameters, validation of of that data, handling of HTTP headers on the response, etc.  CGI was one of the earliest mechanisms for this.  Struts was the de facto web application framework for a nearly ten year period, which ended a few years back.

Within the last few years, a whole new batch of "second generation" web application frameworks have arose.  The shiny new features of these include support for rapid development, support for Ajax, support for unit testing, and adoption of convention over configuration patterns.

So, that should answer your question.  However, as the commentors have suggested, unless your doing some sort of historical research, there's no reason to continue reading about Struts.  Struts2 is a great choice, and there are others.  The topic is a hot one.  And asking which framework is best is a widely panned path on stackoverflow.

Though it's a perfectly valid thought to have, the truth is that it's just not that simple.  If you asking the question in the generic sense, then there is no answer; there are at least 6 six good choices ( I pick the number six purely out of thin air ).  If you have specific requirements for your app, then you can start to make some evaluations.  But, evaluations can only be made with specific requirements in hand.

Comment: Thanks, Actually I think of Struts2 is really one of the best MVC framework, but I think one of the best way to understand it is to know about its history, so I started with struts 1.0 at first, then go to struts2 so that I can tell what's difference between them.

Comment: @Joe.wang  I can certainly appreciate your scholarly attitude.  I'm like that myself.  I would point out though that Struts --> Struts 2 is a misleading lineage.  Struts2 has no code base lineage with Struts 1.x.  There was another framework, WebWork, which became Struts2.  A quick internet search will give you the details.

Comment: @chat  Thank you,you provider us very nice comments and help for learning struts or struts 2. Especially from the author of the book struts in action.